# What is the greatest number of resistances a character can have innately?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, optimization, racial-traits, damage-resistance

A character I am making is a [Feral Tiefling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/feral-tiefling) (SCAG Variant, pg. 118). When creating my character, I started wanting to play a Tiefling, with no class in mind. When I saw the benefits of playing a Feral Tiefling, I was curious if other races started with any number of resistances close to that, or whether by being that race specifically you could gain more.

In the PHB (pg. 43) I saw that [tieflings have the Hellish Resistance racial trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/tiefling#TieflingTraits):

> You have resistance to fire damage.

I also saw the [Infernal Constitution](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/RJSJC2017_04UASkillFeats_24v10.pdf#page=3) racial feat for tieflings in [“Unearthed Arcana: Feats for Races”](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/RJSJC2017_04UASkillFeats_24v10.pdf#page=3):

> Fiendish blood runs strong in you. You gain the following benefits:
>
> - Increase your Constitution score by 1, up to a maximum of 20.
> - You have resistance to cold and poison damage.
> - You have advantage on saving throws against being poisoned.

That's three resistances (fire, cold, and poison).
Does any other race have more resistances than this? Or is this the most (and possibly a little OP)?

I'm not counting resistances from magic items or class features, but feats are alright. I'm interested in the maximum resistances possible at any level. (I'm not counting immunities, but if you want to include those, feel free to do so.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## 3, with the combination you mentioned

With Race/Class/Feat/Magic Item combos, it is relatively simple to rack up Resistance to an absurd range of damage types. But in terms of nothing but Race and Feat...

First place goes to a Tiefling with the Infernal Constitution Feat for 3 resistances

Second place goes to the Volo's Guide Aasimar with 2 resistances

Third Place is shared by Dwarves, Stout Halflings, Tieflings (without the UA Feat), Tritons, and Dragonborn with one resistance each

Comment: Great, thank you!  I don't have access to Volo's so I didn't realize that the Aasimar were expanded upon in that.  I need to get that already!