# How many damage types can a player character become immune to?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, immunities

Reading about [Werewolves](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/werewolf), which are immune to *"Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing from Nonmagical Attacks that aren't Silvered"*, I wondered: How many damage types can a PC become immune to?

For the purpose of this question, assume the following:

- One single character, no outside help from friends
- 20 levels at your disposal
- Multiclassing is allowed
- Feats are allowed
- All official published races + classes are allowed - No UA or other unreleased content
- All magic items except artifacts are allowed
- Preparation time is unlimited
- Assume you have access to unlimited funds and any non-artifact magic item you desire
- No usage of *Wish*

Temporary immunities are nice to have, but the best answer should contain ways to gain as many *permanent* immunities as possible.

Comment: So is the werewolf's immunity considered something like "three *half* damage types", since it isn't immunity to *all* b/p/s, just nonmagical nonsilvered b/p/s?

Comment: I'd call it 3 immunities that are mutually exclusive to p/b/s without those restrictions. IE Immunity to all piercing, then werewolf immunity would still be 3. But they still count as an immunity for the purpose of counting a total (for simplicity).

Comment: @Ifusaso I don't think "mutually exclusive" is correct there, as immunity to all b/p/s includes immunity to nonmagical nonsilvered b/p/s, but the reverse inclusion does not hold. It's definitely a subset relationship.

Comment: If we want to do a full count we'd have to grab all the possible values / combinations like "immune to b/s/p that aren't adamantine", but that kind of goes wild quickly. Let's go with it that the three types count separately, and - if possible - without any restrictions like "non-magical that aren't silvered'. E.g. immunity to bludgeoning is better than "immunity to b from non-magical attacks", if the "full one" exists / can be achieved.

Comment: Related: [What is the greatest number of resistances a character can have innately?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108172)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I meant only for "counting" immunities. I was not trying to imply they were mutually exclusive on a character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I edited so it is only about the asked damage type immunities (my bad). In summary this build has **6 permanent damage type immunities** and **7 temporary damage type immunities** without buffs from friends.

Race:

- Black Dragonborn -> gives resistance to acid

Class:

- 17 level in Wizard for level 9 spell slot
- Any class to wear medium/heavy armor

Items:

- [Periapt of Proof against Poison](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/periapt-of-proof-against-poison) -> immune to **poison damage**
- [Shield of the Uven Rune](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/shield-of-the-uven-rune) (attunement) -> immune to **cold damage**
- [Black Dragon Mask](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/black-dragon-mask) (attunement) -> immune to **acid damage** (since we have acid resistance)

Since we can be level 20 and the preparation time is unlimited we can grind for Epic Boons.

Epic Boons:

- [Boon of the Fire Soul](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/other-rewards#BoonOfTheFireSoul) -> immune to **fire damage**
- [Boon of the Stormborn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/other-rewards#BoonOfTheStormborn) -> immune to **lightning and thunder damage**

Spell:

- [Mind Blank](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-blank) -> **temporary** immune to **psychic damage**
- [Invulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invulnerability) -> **temporary** immune to **all damage** (should be left: **force, piercing, slashing, bludgeoning, radiant, necrotic**)

You could also get [Ring of Fire Elemental Command](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-fire-elemental-command) (attunement) so you only need the Boon of the Stormborn, but the result is the same. Also you don't need Mind Blank since Invulnerability grants immunity to all damage but I find Invulnerability is a too easy answer so I wanted to add this.

Comment: I posted https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/192883/44723 you might want to answer it :)

Comment: Ah of course, the *Invulnerability* spell. Valid way for temp. immunity to all damage types though.

Comment: You can get immunity to cold as a background in Rime of the Frostmaiden, which frees up an item slot.

Comment: Arguably, Mind Blank could be considered "permanent", unlike Invulnerability, since Mind Blank lasts 24 hours and could be renewed day-to-day, such that it's always in effect, unlike Invulnerability, which only lasts 10 minutes (and requires concentration). But yes, being dispellable, and being of a level where casters only get a single slot (so it can't be renewed if dispelled), Mind Blank is not guaranteed to be on all the time.

Answer (score 4):

I think I can get up to **9 permanent immunities**, and then **3-4 temporary immunities**, plus resistance to force damage cause why not.

Race:

- Yuan-ti Pureblood (Volo's Guide to Monsters) - Immunity to Poison

Class:

- 10 Levels in Artificer, subclass doesn't matter but Armorer might help
- 10 Levels in Bard, choosing the College of Lore subclass

With the 10 levels in Artificer, you'll get *Magic Item Adept*, which allows you to attune to up to 4 magic items at once. This is important, because we're going to pick:

- Shield of the Uven Rune - Immunity to Cold
- Armor of Resistance (Artificer Infusion) - Resistance to Acid
- Black Dragon Mask - Immunity to Acid, since we have resistance from the armor
- Absorbing Tattoo, Force - Resistance to Force, with the ability to gain immunity to it once per day

Since we're level 20, we can also get:

- Boon of the Fire Soul - Immunity to Fire
- Boon of the Stormborn - Immunity to Thunder & Lightning

And, last but not least, all we need to do is contract Lycanthropy, which gives us Immunity to Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing damage from weapons that aren't silvered.

This totals up to **9 permanent immunities**.

As for the temporary ones, since we're a 10th level Bard, we get *Magical Secrets*. Multiclassing means that while we're only level 10, we have 8th level spell slots. This means we can take the *Mind Blank* and *Tasha's Otherworldly Guise* spells.

*Mind Blank* gives us Immunity to Psychic damage for 24 hours, and *Tasha's Otherworldly Guise* gives us Immunity to Necrotic *and* Radiant damage for one minute. Additionally, if you wanted resistance to them in the meantime, you can use one of your *Additional Magic Secrets*, since we're a College of Lore Bard, to take the *Hallow* spell. While within the area, creatures you designate can have resistance to one damage type of your choice.

With these spells, and a single turn of Immunity to Force from the tattoo, that gives us the **4 temporary immunities**, meaning that for six seconds, the only thing in the universe that can hurt you are silvered weapons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the same rules apply for bards as everyone else, that you cannot take a spell normally can't cast (spells prepared and known are determined as if you were just a single class), so you can't get Mind Blank and Tashas Otherwordly Guise unless you are at least a level 18 Bard.
*A spell you choose must be of a level you can cast, as shown on the Bard table, or a cantrip.*

Other than that, nice answer.

Comment: I have to say though cursing yourself with Lycanthropy is a very interesting way to gain such immunity, but a nice one.

Answer (score -5):

I am surprised that many are forgetting the boon of immortality which give immunity to time based attacks. Considering a lvl 20 character who has infinite set up would have this boon just for the challenge.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Andy, are you referring to the epic boon in the DMG?

Comment: Time is not a damage type in 5E. While a worthwhile consideration when maximizing immunity, it is not relevant to this specific question. Which is probably contributing to the voting.